# How can I create a markersize legend for a 3D scatter plot with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, legend, scatter-plot

I've created a 3D scatter that uses both color and markersize and independent dimensions. I've added a colorbar legend, but can't figure out how to create a legend for the marker size.

Currently, the plot looks like this:

[image: My current scatter plot:]
Ideally, I'd like to create a legend that has 6 markers of progressively increasing sizes between 0 and 250.

For example:

```
Size | Label
0    | 'Small'
50   | 'Less Small'
100  | 'Getting There'
150  | 'Above Average'
200  | 'Pretty Big'
250  | 'Large'
```

Here's the code that's generating the plot. The input variables xp, yp, zp, cp, and co are lists that I've generated elsewhere.

```
mat.style.use(['ggplot'])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15));

norm = mat.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(co), vmax=max(co))
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.RdBu)
cc = list()
    for v in co:
cc.append(mapper.to_rgba(v))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d');
ax.scatter(xp, yp, zp, s=cp, c=cc, depthshade=True, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black');

mapper.set_array(cc)
plt.colorbar( mapper, label='Count' )

y = lambda x: (np.tanh(-x*50.)+1.)*250
x = np.arange(0,.05,.01)

sizes = y(x)
labels = x

# I can't figure out what to do here:
l = ax.legend(sizes, scatterpoints = len(sizes))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is to add some dummy data from which the legend is built.

```
sizes = np.arange(0, 300, 50)
labels = ['size={0}'.format(s) for s in sizes]

points = [ax.scatter([], [], [], s=s, c='gray') for s in sizes]
plt.legend(points, labels, scatterpoints=1)
```

This adds some empty artist objects to the plot, which are then used to populate the legend. You can adjust the color, transparency, etc. via the empty objects, and this will be reflected in the legend.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!